# Detect the last written word when typing TAB in a textarea or contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, contenteditable

**How to detect and select the last written word when <kbd>TAB</kbd> is pressed in a `textarea` or contenteditable `div`?**

I started to do it with a buffer of the last characters written or key-presses, but then I noticed that there are multiple corner cases:

- let's say the user writes <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>
- the user moves with arrow keys
- the user can separate words with <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (that's what I was using) but also <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or a comma, etc.

Is there a nice way to detect the last written word?

Goal: to code an autocomplete feature, example: `thx + <TAB>` => Text is replaced by "Thank you very much."

Comment: I think you would have to log all keystrokes and then just reset what you are logging if the user types certain characters like a space or using the arrow keys

Comment: @Pete That's what I started to do, but then I ran into multiple corner cases (see the first one listed for example...)

Comment: Why would you want the last word typed - why not just the last word in the text area?  What happens if the last word typed is the first word in the sentence or what happens if the last thing typed is part of a word - eg the user moves their cursor to fix a word they spelt wrong?  perhaps on tab press you can get where the cursor was in the textarea and then select that word?

Comment: Example: I write `The sky blue`, then I move the cursor after `sky` and I type `is`. Then I press `TAB`: the detected word should be `is`. It's not the last word in the textarea (which is `blue`), but it's the last written word... Another way to say it is that it's the *last word before cursor*, it would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally works for `textarea` and for `contenteditable` div:

```js
var newText = 'hello\nnewline';
var newHtml = '<b>test</b> and<br>a <a href="hjkh">link</a>';

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var elt = e.target;
    if (elt.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea' || elt.isContentEditable)
    {        
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (elt.isContentEditable) {  // for contenteditable
                elt.focus();
                sel = document.getSelection();
                sel.modify("extend", "backward", "word");
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                console.log(range.toString().trim());
                range.deleteContents();
                var el = document.createElement("div");
                el.innerHTML = newHtml;
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node;
                while (node = el.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(frag);
                range.collapse();
            } else {  // for texterea/input element
                var endingIndex = elt.selectionStart;
                var startingIndex = endingIndex && endingIndex - 1;
                var value = elt.value;
                var regex = /[ ]/;
                while (startingIndex > -1) {
                    if (regex.test(value[startingIndex])) {
                        ++startingIndex;
                        break;
                    }
                    --startingIndex;
                }
                if (startingIndex < 0) {
                    startingIndex = 0;
                }
                value = value.substring(0, startingIndex) + newText + value.substring(endingIndex);
                var cursorPosition = startingIndex + newText.length;
                e.target.value = value;
                e.target.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Hello, press TAB to replace this WORD<br>Also press TAB after this ONE</div>
<textarea rows="8" cols="50" id="a">Hello, press TAB to replace this WORD
Also press TAB after this ONE</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use current cursor position to detect last word. A simple example is given bellow.

```js
document.getElementById('foobar').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if( e.which == 9 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let endingIndex = e.target.selectionStart;
    let startingIndex = endingIndex && endingIndex - 1;
    let value = e.target.value;
    // putt all delemeters in it by which word can be splitted
    let regex = /[ ]/;

    while(startingIndex > -1){
      if(regex.test(value[startingIndex])){
        ++startingIndex;
        break;
      }
      --startingIndex;
    }

    // note you will have you apply check to avoid negative index
    if(startingIndex < 0) {
        startingIndex = 0;
    }
    console.log(value.substring(startingIndex, endingIndex));

    let newText = "replaced";
    value = value.substring(0, startingIndex) + newText + value.substring(endingIndex);
    let cursorPosition = startingIndex + newText.length;
    e.target.value = value;
    e.target.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<textarea id="foobar"></textarea>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks @RehanHaider! PS: would it be possible to also replace the found word in the textarea by a text "REPLACED"?

Comment: Yes easily, you can use `startingIndex` and `endingIndex` to replace that portion and set value of `textarea` with new value.

Comment: Could you add this in your code @RehanHaider (just to be sure to understand how it works)? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last thing @RehanHaider: it doesn't work on a `<div contenteditable></div>`. What should we modify to make it work with them? And also it should work with HTML `newText = "Hello <a href='/'>you</a>"`

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience with `contenteditable`. After quick testing it seems that most of events don't work with `contenteditables` :(

Comment: A little corner case @RehanHaider, if a line of textarea is " hi" then the detected word is " hi" and not "hi". Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172927/discussion-between-rehan-haider-and-basj).